# Replace one Qt icon with another

Tags: c++, qt, styles, icons

I would like to replace the checkbox icon in a checkable QGroupBox with the open/close icon from QTreeView. I have found examples of how to replace the check icon by setting the QCheckBox::inidicator style, but I don't know how to get the icon set for QTreeView. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You need png icon set? Have you look it at this location: qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/images ?